# Do I have to rebuild my frontend for production every time I edit it? I'm using Vue

Tags: vue.js, frontend, vue-component

Basically what I have is my frontend (Vue) and my backend (Node.js and etc.). By following a guide, I've built the frontend for production using  `npm run build`. I got a bunch of files in a build folder I setup within a previous step. These files were then moved to a folder in the backend. It works, but it's more a demo than anything else, and the frontend and backend will have to be modified more as I continue.

I'm just wondering if and when I edit the fronted more (let's say, when I add a new page) am I supposed to go through this process again? So I'll modify the front end folder, build that, move files, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to do it each time to have the most recent changes. But that seems like a production release process, which you should do once your application is production ready. You should try configuring dev environment for the development purpose (npm run dev).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely.

If we are in a development environment, we use `npm run dev` or `yarn run` which upholds the development environment running and updates the browser whenever any modifications inside the code happen. **We don't use any final build in the development environment because we make code modifications so repeatedly that it would be a sore process to make a build after every modification and check the results using that build.**

But, the production is distinct from the development environment. **We deploy the only code which is bug-free, entirely working, and ready for users to use.** Deploying to production means all changes have been made, and the final code is ready to be deployed. **So, we make a final production build and deploy it to our server.**

So, don't panic to deploy to production every time you make a small change in the code. First, complete your all changes, and test the changes in the development environment, if everything is working correctly then only create a final production build, and deploy it to the server.**

I hope this helps.